# Converting from lat/long to EPSG:2154, in C#?

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, epsg

I don't know much about GIS. I'm working in C#.
I'm receiving latitude/longitude data and need to convert them to EPSG:2154.

I've done some web search but I'm still not sure where to start.
Is there some kind of library or code examples I could use ?

Comment: [Proj4j](https://proj4net.codeplex.com/) is the standard library for coordinate transforms and there is a .net version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proj.4 ([git page here](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4)) is a C/C++ library that has wrappers for many different languages and could be considered industry standard. There are C# wrappers [available here](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/) as well as a command line versions of Proj.4.

Proj4NET is a library for transforming coordinates, it mainly ports Proj4J. [Here is the link to the homepage](https://proj4net.codeplex.com/).

There are other options as well:

- [GDAL/OGR C# Bindings](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp), specifically the OSGeo.OSR library
- [Proj.NET](http://projnet.codeplex.com/)
- [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/), specifically the Projections library

It is a bit confusing as Proj.NET and Proj4Net have such similar names but they are different libraries that provide the same functionality.

Comment: After checking what Nuget package seem the most used, I went with "ProjNet4GeoAPI". Yet another confusing name? Still struggling a bit with it but I think I'll open another question. (I'll check your answer as I don't see anything wrong with it anyway.)

Comment: And I just noticed that ProjNet4GeoAPI is actually derived from Proj.NET.